# Git feature branches workflow

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase, git-remote

I am trying to contribute to a project and I'd like to use git-flow workflow(?) on what I work.
Say, I have checkout'd the `develop` branch of the remote repository (github) and that I've setup 2 feature branches (T for Translation, U for Update):

```
---o---o---o (D)
           |---Ta---Tb (T)
           \---Ua---Ub---Uc (U)
```

Now, for each of the branches, a pull request is made to the `upstream` repository maintainer and he accepts them all and merges them to the `upstream/develop` branch.

What is the correct procedure so that I end up with:

```
---o---o---Ta---Tb---Ua---Ub---Uc (D)
                               |- (T)
                               \- (U)
```

Something tells me that `git rebase` is what I need. (Please note I am on Windows).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right. You (or the repository maintainer) needs to rebase your changes onto your develop branch:

```
git checkout develop
git rebase T
git rebase U
```

During the rebase, you might need to resolve conflicts if they occur.

Your last branch diagram shows T and U have Uc as their parent. The rebase won't change the branches parent. You can do this by deleting your branches and recreating them after the rebasing above.

```
git branch -D T
git branch -D U
```

You'll need to use the capital -D switch to force the branch deletion because the T and U branch was never merged into the develop branch, so git doesn't know that the branch changes are reflected in the `develop` branch.

After that, you can recreate them:

```
git checkout -b T

git checkout develop
git checkout -b U
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that conflicts will occur if the upstream developer has made any changes _other_ than merging the two feature branches.

Comment: This will only change the `develop` branch. Then you need to move the other branches using for example `git branch -M`.

Comment: So basically, after the pull requests have been accepted and the `upstream/develop` has been updated with my changes, I go ahead and `git pull upstream/develop` into my `develop` and then what do I do?

  a. Make a rebase from `T` & `U` respectively to my `develop`
  b. Delete my `T` & `U` branches and recreate them

Comment: Delete your T & U branches and recreate them if you want.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I was hoping that there would be a clear way to make this happen with rebase, but anyhow, it is as it is. Thanks for the answer.